# Mechanize Browser Timeout Not Working

Tags: python, timeout, mechanize

I am having an issue with `mechanize`'s `timeout` feature. On most pages it works perfectly, if the URL fails to load in a reasonable amount of time it raises an error: `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error timed out>`. However, on certain pages the timer does not work and the program becomes unresponsive even to a keyboard interrupt. Here is an example page where that occurs:

```
import mechanize

url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/20141104183547/http://www.dallasnews.com/'

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
html = br.open(url, timeout=0.01).read() #hangs on this page, timeout set extremely low to trigger timeout on all pages for debugging
```

First, does this script hang for other people for this particular URL? Second, what could be going wrong/how do I debug?

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why that url request hangs up for mechanize but using urllib2; the request comes back fine.  Maybe they have some code that recognizes mechanize despite setting robots to false.

I think urllib2 should be a good solution for your situation

```
import mechanize
import urllib2
url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/20141104183547/http://www.dallasnews.com/'

try:
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
    html = br.open(url).read() #set_handle_robots
except:
    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16'}) 
    con = urllib2.urlopen( req )
    html = con.read()
print html
```

Comment: Mechanize works fine on the rest of the site. The issue is not with getting a result, but with failing to terminate when it hits the timeout.